# How to loop a countdown pattern in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to repeat a countdown pattern 4 times using a while loop but it's not cooperating. 
Basically, I want it to first start count downing from 5 seconds, and then from 10 seconds and I want this to repeat 4 times. 
The code worked, but once I put it in a while loop or any loop for that matter, it skips like 4 seconds and it doesn't repeat. 
I also tried a do while and a for loop but they didn't change anything, it still didn't loop 4 times. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Relevant JS Code:

```
function startCountDown() {
    let reps = 1
    while (reps <= 4) {
        setInterval(studyCountDown, 1000);
        reps++

    }
}

function studyCountDown() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(studyTime / 60)
    let seconds = studyTime % 60

    if (seconds >= 0) {
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        countdownOutput.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`
        studyTime--;
    }
    else {
        breakCountDown()
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `studyTime`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `setInterval` in loop executes asynchronously but the good thing is, it works, just not as expected. I would recommend you to rather have a global variable tracking your loop inside setInterval which executes your function to handle the countdown.

I've modified your logic a bit just as I found mine work good for this demo snippet.

```js
var loop = 1
var seconds = 5
var counter = 1
var interval = null

function startCountDown() {
  document.getElementById("attempts").innerHTML = `Attempt: ${loop}`
  interval = setInterval(studyCountDown, 1000);
}

function studyCountDown() {
  if (counter <= 5) {
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = `${counter}`
    counter++;
  } else {
    loop++;
    if (loop > 4) {
      document.getElementById("attempts").innerHTML = `Done`
      document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = ``
      clearLoop();
    } else {
      seconds = 5;
      counter = 1;
      document.getElementById("attempts").innerHTML = `Attempt: ${loop}`
      document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = ``
    }
  }

}

function clearLoop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="startCountDown()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="attempts"></p>
<p id="counter"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although it works, it is not quite what I want my code to do. Every loop you add 5 seconds to the counter. I want to repeat 5 second countdown 4 times, without adding anything. Also, the attempts counter decrements while I want it to increment, so that it goes: ```1, 2, 3, 4  Done!``` If you can help out with this, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Oh great, might be I understood your use case wrong from your question. I've edited the snippet. Hope this answers your question.